# Unhandled Exception Future dynamic is not a subtype of type FutureOr List Books

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

how to pass Data of `Future<dynamic>` to `Future<List<dynamic>>`

```
getall(BuildContext context, String url, String type) async {
  final response = await http.get(url, headers: { 
 'Accept': 'application/json' 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
  });
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  switch(type){
  case "Chapters":
            List responseJson = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
            return responseJson.map((m) => new Subjects.fromJson(m)).toList();
            break;
   case "Subjects":
            List responseJson = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
            return responseJson.map((m) => new Chapters.fromJson(m)).toList();
            break; 
 } 
}
}
```

This is the function I want to get data from `getall`:

```
Future<List<Subjects>> getsubjects(BuildContext context, String url, String type) async {
  return getall(context, url, type);

Future<List<Chapters>> getchapters(BuildContext context, String url, String type) async {
  return getall(context, url, type);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the return type for the `getall` function should fix this.

```dart
Future<List<Subjects>> getall(BuildContext context, String url, String type) async {
  final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
  });


  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List responseJson = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
    return responseJson.map((m) => new Subjects.fromJson(m)).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are 100% right but  i want to get same data for different Functions  like for                
                `Future<List<Chapters>> getchapters(BuildContext context, String url, String type) async {
  return getall(context, url, type);
}`

Comment: `getall(BuildContext context, String url, String type) async {
  final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
  });


  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List responseJson = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
    return responseJson.map((m) => new Subjects.fromJson(m)).toList();
  }
}`